# Excel sumif function with conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, date-range, sumifs

I need to sum a column with alot of variables and i am having trouble when making it. ( see picture for reference)

I need to sum G (Sum time) if its less than 300 (<300), if B (Type) =1, if D (date) = input cell  and if E( time) = a certain range that i can change, for example "7pm -12pm"

I don't have a ton of experaicen with having these conditions, this is what i have tried so far.

```
sumif(Table1[[ type]]=1, IF(Table1[[#All],[Date]]=K3, AND(Table1[[#All],[Time]]=K4, IF(Table1[[#All],[Sum Time (sec)]]=<300))))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Picture here : [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtqjE.png]

Comment: This condition is not clear - ```Table1[[#All],[Time]] = K4```. What is entered in cell ```K4```? Or, better, show us all the input cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

```
=sumifs(table1[sum time (sec)],Table1[type],1, Table1[Date],K3, Table1[Time],K4, Table1[Sum Time (sec)],"<300")
```

Comment: Unfortunately it returns #value

Comment: Try entering it manually from scratch by typing =SUMIFS and selecting the ranges. It works for me. Do you have non-numeric values in the last column?

Comment: retyped it and  and checked the last column currently its on general, though i copy and pasted it as value and tried with number, all 3 got rid of the #value but it provides a 0 which is incorrect

Comment: I'll have a look tomorrow. In the meantime build it up one condition at a time to see what's going on. If you read up on SUMIFS you should be able to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Btw if you’re doing a time range you will need two criteria. A start time and end time.

Comment: Looks like it's worked! Thanks mate you are a legend!